# How to open a .txt file and apply an equation to each line successively in C

Tags: c

i have to write a code for university in which i have to read a .txt file that contains three columns: Hour of the day, Solar radiation, Rain meter (mm), and apply a equation to each line consecutively based on information given by the user. i managed to build the code that applies the equation for a single line chosen by the user at a time. How can i apply that equation to every line and display them simultaneously ?

The .txt file i'm using is:

```
0   -0.82   17.2
1   2386    14.4
2   1980    0.22
3   470 0.0
4   2731    0.2
5   1531    0.0
6   3084    0.4
7   2197    0.4
8   313 0.0
9   1428    0.0
10  47.01   0.0
11  138.8   0.0
12  328.4   0.0
13  431.2   0.4
14  419.6   0.2
15  447.8   0.8
16  572.2   0.2
17  801.5   0.0
18  849.1   0.0
19  561.1   0.0
20  376.6   0.0
21  122.9   0.0
22  -1.69   0.0
23  -1.46   0.0
```

my code is as follow (please forgive the unpolishness, i'm a begginer in programming):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define efi  0.83 //83% , standart solar cell eficiency

int h,a;


int potency (int x, int y, int z)
{
    return (x*y*z);
}

int hour[24], i=0;
float radiation[24], rain[24], energ,energk,pt,p,e,ep,ee;



int main()
{



   FILE *arq;

   arq = fopen("file2.txt", "r");
   if(arq == NULL) {
      printf("Error! unable to open file! \n");
      getchar();
   }
   else {
      printf("File open... \n");
      printf("Reading file...\n");
      while (!feof(arq)){
         fscanf(arq,"%d %f %f\n", &hour[i], &radiation[i], &rain[i]);
         i++;
      }
    printf("Type desired hour \n");
      scanf("%d", &h);
    printf("type board area m^2\n");
      scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("type maximum board pontency in WATTS/M^2\n");
      scanf("%f", &p);
      ep=p*efi; //Board potential after calculated its standart eficiency
    printf("Total eficiency of the board is %.2f %", ep);
    pt=  a*ep;
    printf("Total board potential is %.2f\n", pt);

        energ= (pt*radiacao[h]); // generated energy
        energk=(float)energ/1000; // generated energy in kw


      printf("At %d hoour, there is an average of %.2f KW/m^2 radiation\n %.2f mm of rain\n and the total energy produced by the board will be %.2f Kw \n ", hour[h], radiation[h], rain[h], energk);
      printf("\n\n\n press <enter> to finish");
      getchar();
   }
   fclose(arq);
}
```

Comment: Step 1: Check the return value of `fscanf(arq,"%d %f %f\n", &hour[i], &radiation[i], &rain[i]);` - see if it is 3.

Comment: Who or what text suggested using `while (!feof(arq)){`?  Why is code loop 25 times?  Better to prevent a 25th iteration.

Comment: my professor =/

Comment: didn't realize the 25th one ! thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>

  #define efi  0.83 //83% , standart solar cell eficiency

  int h,a;


  int potency (int x, int y, int z)
  {
     return (x*y*z);
 }

 int hour[24], i=0;
 float radiation[24], rain[24], energ,energk,pt,p,e,ep,ee;



int main()
{



  FILE *arq;

  arq = fopen("file2.txt", "r");
  if(arq == NULL) {
     printf("Error! unable to open file! \n");
     getchar();
  }
  else {
     printf("File open... \n");
     printf("Reading file...\n");
     while (!feof(arq)){
        fscanf(arq,"%d %f %f\n", &hour[i], &radiation[i], &rain[i]);
        i++;
     }
     printf("type board area m^2\n");   
     scanf("%d", &a);
     printf("type maximum board pontency in WATTS/M^2\n");
     scanf("%f", &p);
     ep=p*efi; //Board potential after calculated its standart eficiency
     printf("Total eficiency of the board is %.2f %", ep);
     pt=  a*ep;
     printf("Total board potential is %.2f\n", pt);

     int i;
     for(i = 0; i < 24; i++)
     {
       energ= (pt*radiation[i]); // generated energy
       energk=(float)energ/1000; // generated energy in kw


       printf("At %d hoour, there is an average of %.2f KW/m^2 radiation\n %.2f mm of rain\n and the total energy produced by the board will be %.2f Kw \n ", i, radiation[i], rain[i], energk);

     }
     scanf("%d", &a);
  }
  fclose(arq);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help but for some reason the program stops right after 
    


printf("Total eficiency of the board is %.2f %", ep);
    pt=  a*ep;
    printf("Total board potential is %.2f\n", pt)





the command "for" is not executing for some reason

Comment: Try this. Have no idea where is the trouble in your version, because cannot see your code

Comment: Thanks a lot i found the issue why it was not seeing the FOR command, i adjusted the "WHILE" command and merged with the "FOR" and it worked, thanks a lot !!

while (!feof(arq)){
        fscanf(arq,"%d %f %f\n", &hour[i], &radiation[i], &rain[i]);
        i++;

this command was crashing with the 


for(i = 0; i < 24; i++)
     {
       energ= (pt*radiation[i]); // generated energy
       energk=(float)energ/1000; // generated energy in kw